# Is it correct to use 'la que' in 'La chica a *la que* vi ayer se llama Ana'?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

I have a grammar question about a sentence below.

> La chica **a la** que vi ayer se llama Ana.

In my point of view, we should use "la que" in this sentence and I think that it is grammatically correct. If it is not, please let me know why?

And also if I say:

> La chica **que** vi ayer se llama Ana.

Is it correct as well?

Answer (score 3):

Both are perfectly fine. The trick is that the *ver* verb has [a lot of meanings](http://dle.rae.es/?id=baOo6Gz), and depending on the sentence its meaning can be different. If you just say:

> La chica que vi ayer se llama Ana.

Here I would say that you just *saw* the girl as you were walking down the street of whatever. Another interpretation could be that you are a doctor and the girl came to you so that you could check her. But if you say:

> La chica a la que vi ayer se llama Ana.

Now the *ver* verb could be interpreted as *meet*: you saw the girl because you had an appointment to go see her. But this is indeed quite prone to interpretations and the final meaning of the sentences will depend on the context.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better with couple of colons? "La chica, a la que vi ayer, se llama Ana" similar to "La chica, la cual vi ayer, se llama Ana". I don't think using "la que" is incorrect but it sounds weird to me and I prefer "La chica que vi ayer..." even if we had an appointment. Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

"La chica **a la que**..."  It sounds incorrect.

To become correct would be

> La chica **que vi** ayer.

Or

> La chica **a la cual** vi ayer.

In the case of a boy would be:

> El chico **que vi** ayer.

Or

> El chico **al que** vi ayer.

Or

> El chico **al cual** vi ayer.

Comment: in case of  "La chica, a la cual vi ayer."  do we have to put coma(,) between  "La chica, a" ??

Comment: @IanLee actually that comma was a typo. Is not needed there. I removed already.

Comment: Why would "El chico al que vi ayer" be fine while "La chica a la que vi ayer" is not?